# Consuming API endpoints inside of a Dictionary of arrays - Swift 4

Tags: json, nsdictionary, swift4

I know the question sounds weird but I don't know another way to ask this, first of all, I am playing with the Pokemon API and I am new in swift. what is my problem I am parsing the data to show Pokemon information but the endpoint to show pokemon comes like this:

https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/

```
{
  "count": 949,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
              {
               "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/",
               "name": "bulbasaur"
              },
              {
               "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/",
               "name": "ivysaur"
              },
             {
               "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/",
               "name": "venusaur"
             },
```

With a name and other URL to see more about a specific pokemon. I could get the dictionary of array and I can show the pokemon name but I don't know how to get the other data that is in the other endpoint.

This is my code for now:

```
@IBAction func generatePokemon(_ sender: Any) {
    // TODO: Improve API request
    let apiUrl = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon")

    let request = URLRequest(url: apiUrl!)
    // Request to Pokemon API
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            // Optional binding to get data
            if let data = data {
                let parsedResult: [String:AnyObject]!
                do {
                    parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                    if let resultDictonary = parsedResult["results"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]  {
                        print(resultDictonary[0])
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("Error in parse json")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

So I am not sure if I need to create another function to get the data of that endpoint and then call that inside my generatePokemon function so I can fill the view with more information? or what is the best way to consume that data.

Here is my repo too if someone wanna see it I have a branch there where I am doing all this first network request.

[Github](https://github.com/Fevaldivia/PokeCards)

Thank for your time guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I did something like what you need here is my repo:

https://bitbucket.org/pokemonred/pokedexgr2/

Check for the branch pokedexSebas, if you have any questions let me know.
I'm using alamofire to perform the requests.

In the repo you have to take a look into two clases, the first one is: SBBackendManager and SebasObjectMapper.

In the SBBackendManager I have these 2 methods:

```
func getAllPokemon () { // This will retrieve all pokemon

    let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<SPokemonApiResponse>) in

        let pokemonResponse = response.result.value

        if let sPokeArray = pokemonResponse?.resultados {

            contador = sPokeArray.count

        }
    }
}

func getPokemon(_ url:String){ // This will retrieve a single pokemon

    Alamofire.request(url).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<SPokemon>) in

        let spokemon = response.result.value

        pokemonArray += [spokemon!]
        contador = contador! - 1
    }
}
```

And on SebasObjectMapper I have this:

```
class SPokemonApiResponse:Mappable{
    var resultados:[SPokemonResult]?
    required init?(map: Map) {  }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        resultados <- map["results"]
    }
}

class SPokemonResult:Mappable {
    var url:String? {
        didSet {  // HERE: every time a result is added to the array will trigger the get a single pokemon method
            let bm = SBackendManager()
            bm.getPokemon(url!)
        }   
    }
    required init(map:Map) {}
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        url <- map["url"]
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you still working on this project? I am having problems finding the line of code that consumes the second endpoint inside of the dictionary of arrays, sorry I am just starting with the networks connection and stuff so is still kind of hard for me to visualize.